# AWS Lambda callback node js too fast

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to copy the thumbnail example that is in the AWS documentation ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html)). I want to use this thumbnail as soon as it is created. I hoped the context.done() callback would be sufficient. The callback is giving me a nice response, but it is too soon. Not always is the image resized and available in the s3 bucket it is stored. On invoking the lambda function I especially set the invocation type to "Event" so the callback should come back after the function is done resizing.

Given the example in the documentation what would be the propper way of waiting for the whole lambda function to be done? The function that invokes the lambda function in my application now looks like:

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./configs/config.json');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
var params = {
 FunctionName: 'resizeImage',
 InvocationType: 'Event',
 Payload: JSON.stringify({key: req.body.key})
};
lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
 } else {
  console.log(data);           // successful response
  next();
 }
});
```

Comment: Is your bucket in us-east-1, and have you looked at [consistency model](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_data_consistency_model_does_Amazon_S3_employ) as an explanation?

Comment: I am using zone eu-west-1, and consistency models does not seems to bee the problem, my CloudWatch logs show me the correct time it takes to complete the lambda function in ms, only my application is called before that. App gets response after 500ms while the lambda function takes about 2000ms to complete.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my question. I messed up the invocation types you can provide when invoking the function. There are three ways of invocation and in my question I'm using the "Event" type. This causes the lambda function to give a direct (and thus async response), the function may  not be finished yet. Changing the invocation type to "RequestResponse" provides an synch response where we want to wait for our function to be done.

See also the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Excellent work, finding your own solution.  Indeed, you do seem to have a valid case for waiting on the function to complete.  If you need it *now* rather than "really soon," it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't block waiting for the `Lambda` to complete. Instead, you should publish your `S3 Events` to a `SNS Topic` and then process these events in your application. This will guarantee that your objects are in place when you access them.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! but doesn't this seems a bit heavy . Since this lambda function is called just after a image is uploaded I want to wait till the function to finish. If sns topics are the only way to go I will keep that in mind.

Comment: I'd recommend the S3 approach or you can ping your app back from the Lambda itself.

Comment: I will think about this tomorrow if this is the solution I will let you know, thanks for the input just now.

Comment: It was a simple mistake. I messed up the InvocationTypes. I changed the InvocationType from "Event" to "RequestResponse",and the callback changed from a async to a synchronised (and preferred) response. Glad you provided some good alternatives though!